# integral and differential problem from my lecture 1

Tags: integration, derivatives

i got this problem from my lecture, 
 1. integral equation, i need to know step by step to got the answer 
    $$\int y^3 \sin(2x) dx$$ 
    my friends said the answer is $-y^3 \cos^2(x)$, but i don't know how to get this.

1. differential equation, 
   a. $\frac{Dm}{dy} (3y^2 + y \sin (2xy))$ 
   b. $\frac{Dn}{dx}( 6xy + x \sin (2xy))$ 
   my friend said again two of them have same answer, it said 6y + sin 2xy + 2xy cos 2xy 
   but once again i don't know how to get thia,

   someone can tell me step by step please, i really appreciate it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Those aren't differential equations.  A differential equation needs a derivative of something present, like $y^\prime=y$.

Comment: What is $m$ and $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to find:

$$
\int y^3\sin(2x)dx,
$$

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(3y^2+y\sin(2xy))
$$and

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(6xy+x\sin(2xy))
$$

The first is an integral with respect to $x$, so we can pull the $y^3$ out: 
$$
\int y^3\sin(2x)dx=y^3\int\sin(2x)dx=y^3\left(-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)+C\right)
$$ so your friend is incorrect.

For the second, we differentiate with respect to $y$ so $x$ is treated as a constant:

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(3y^2+y\sin(2xy))=6y+\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(y\sin(2xy))=6y+\sin(2xy)+2xy\cos(2xy)
$$  so your friend is correct.  For the third, we differentiate with respect to $x$ so $y$ is treated as a constant:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(6xy+x\sin(2xy))=6y+\sin(2xy)+2yx\cos(2xy)
$$so that one is correct as well.